# Проблема с классом на php

Tags: php

```
    class Contacts extends DataBase {

   public $sql_select;

   function SQL () {
        if (!$_SESSION['lang'] or $_SESSION['lang'] == "_ru") {
            $sql = mysql_query("select id, name, status, skype, icq, email, cell, facebook from users");
        } else {
            $sql = mysql_query("select id, name".$_SESSION['lang'].", status, skype, icq, email, cell, facebook from users");
        }

        if (!$sql) {echo mysql_error();}

        $this->sql_select = $sql;
   }

   function ins_cont () {

        $sql_array = mysql_fetch_array($this->sql_select);

        do {
           $id = $sql_array['id'];
           $name = $sql_array['name'.$_SESSION['lang'].''];
           $status = $sql_array['status'];
           $skype = $sql_array['skype'];
           $icq = $sql_array['icq'];
           $email = $sql_array['email'];
           $cell = $sql_array['cell'];
           $facebook = $sql_array['facebook'];

           require'theme/contacts.php';
        } while($sql_array = mysql_fetch_array($this->sql_select));
   }
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects
> parameter 1 to be resource, null given
> in

Толкового ответа в Сети не нашел и не могу разобраться, как исправить.

Comment: @kiberchainik, вы пишете в `$this->sql_array`, а запрашиваете `$this->sql_select`. Сразу скажу, что писать в одном методе, а читать в другом - это очень опасный антипаттерн.

Comment: вот еслиб на русском объяснили или на мануал натолкнули, был бы благодарен )) и все равно ошибка остается той же

Comment: @kiberchainik, значит второй метод выполняется раньше первого. О чем я примерно и говорил про антипаттерн. Первый метод должен выполняться ***внутри*** второго и не проставлять свойства объекту (***не изменять состояние*** объекта), а возвращать значение.

Answer (score 1):

Как я решил проблему: я просто первую функцию переименовал в __construct(), после этого все заработало, если же я в чем-то не прав, объясните, научите. ) Спасибо всем, кто отозвался. )

Comment: @kiberchainik ну, во-первых, нужно просто читать комментарии

> значит второй метод выполняется раньше первого. О чем я примерно и говорил про антипаттерн.

во-вторых, этот метод не имеет никакого отношения к конструкции класса и ни в коме случае не должен объявляться конструктором.

Answer (score 0):

Какой-то из запросов некорректен.

```
 if (!$_SESSION['lang'] or $_SESSION['lang'] == "_ru") {
            $sql = mysql_query("select id, name, status, skype, icq, email, cell, facebook from users");
           echo "запрос 1";
        } else {
            $sql = mysql_query("select id, name".$_SESSION['lang'].", status, skype, icq, email, cell, facebook from users");
           echo "запрос 2";
        }
```

Проверьте для начала, какое из условий срабатывает, чтобы знать, в каком запросе искать ошибку. Также проверьте значение `$_SESSION['lang']`, если оно используется (запрос 2).

И ещё `$name = $sql_array['name'.$_SESSION['lang'].''];`, если сработал запрос 1, то не будет у вас такой ячейки в `$sql_array`.

Comment: нет, в запросах все работает верно, то, что я тут написал, было сначала одной функцией, затем мне понадобилось разделить ее на две, именно такие. Как я решил проблему: я просто первую функцию переименовал в __construct(), после этого все заработало